# Given a bounded set $E$, there is a $G_\delta$ set such that the outer measures are equal

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:** Show that for any bounded set $E \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ for which $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(E)=m^*(G)$.

Let $\{I_n\}$ be a countable collection of open intervals such that $E \subset \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$.  Observe the following: $$m^*(E) \leq m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n) \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n) < m^*(E)+\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Now let $G=\bigcap\bigcup I_n$.  $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set.  From this, we see that $E \subset G$.  Thus for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $$m^*(E) \leq m^*(G) \leq m^*(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n) \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n) < m^*(E)+\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

So we take $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You should denote $I_{n,j}$ the collection of intervals which covers $E$ and approach up to $2^{-n}$ the outer measure of $E$ (which is finite). Here you take $n$ as an index, but we see $n$ outside the sum, and we don't know what it is. But you saw the idea and you just have to take now $G:=\bigcap_{j\geq 1}\bigcup_{n\geq 1}I_{n,j}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each integer $n\geq 1$, let $\{I_{n,j}\}$ be a countable collection of open intervals which covers $E$ such that $$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}m^*(I_{n,j})\leqslant m^*(E)+n^{-1}.$$
Such a collection exists because the outer measure of $E$ is finite, as $E$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$.

Let $G:=\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{j\geq 1}I_{n,j}$. As $\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}I_{n,j}$ is open for each $n$, $G$ is a countable intersection of open sets, and it contains $E$. For $n\geqslant 1$, the following inequalities hold
$$m^*(G)\leqslant m^*\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{+\infty}I_{n,j}\right) \leqslant\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}m^*\left(I_{n,j}\right) \leqslant m^*(E)+n^{-1},$$
which concludes the proof.

Comment: Is the assumption that E is bounded necessary? Royden's definition of outer measure uses inf, so even if the set is not bounded, can't we still find "such a collection"?

Comment: @hl0202 I was thinking the same thing...

Comment: How do you approximate to an unbounded set from the outside?

Comment: Since this is outer measure and not Lebesgue measure, don't we have to assume countable subadditivity instead of additivity which means that $m^*(\cup_j I_{n,j}) \leq \sum_j m^*(I_{n,j}$?

Comment: @CarlGanz You are right. I have corrected.